# How to execute a select and count in one query in Yii

Tags: php, sql, yii

I want to execute this SQL query in Yii:

```
select count(id), userID from tableName where type = 'admin' and dateAdded between '2018-07-01' and '2018-08-01' group by userID
```

Is there any way to run this query in a `findAll()`, `countAll()` or some other Yii method? I don't want to use `findAllBySQL()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following solution to execute a select and count in one statement:

```
$model=Model::find()->where([your conditions])->count();
```

Answer (score 0):

## Yii 1.1

```
$data = MyModel::model()->findAll([
    'select' => [
        'count(id) as count', 
        'userID'
    ],
    'condition' => "type = 'admin' and dateAdded between '2018-07-01' and '2018-08-01'",
    'group' => 'userID',
]);
```

You need to also add `count` property to `MyModel`:

```
class MyModel extends CActiveRecord {

    public $count;

    // ...
}
```

Then you can map counts to IDs:

```
$counts = CHtml::listData($data, 'userId', 'count');
```

Or access it in foreach:

```
foreach ($data as $model) {
    echo "$model->userID - $model->count\n";
}
```

## Yii 2

```
$data = Post::find()
    ->select([
        'count(id) as count',
        'userID',
    ])
    ->where("type = 'admin' and dateAdded between '2018-07-01' and '2018-08-01'")
    ->groupBy('userID')
    ->asArray()
    ->all();
```

Mapping:

```
$counts = ArrayHelper::map($data, 'userID', 'count');
```

Foreach:

```
foreach ($data as $row) {
    echo "{$row['userID']} - {$row['count']}\n";
}
```